# Calculate (approximately) if zip64 extensions are required without relying on exceptions?

Tags: python, zip

I have the following requirements (from the client) for zipping a number of files.

If the zip file created is less than 2**31-1 ~2GB use compression to create it (use zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED), otherwise do not compress it (use zipfile.ZIP_STORED).

The current solution is to compress the file without zip64 and catching the zipfile.LargeZipFile exception to then create the non-compressed version.

My question is whether or not it would be worthwhile to attempt to calculate (approximately) whether or not the zip file will exceed the zip64 size without actually processing all the files, and how best to go about it? The process for zipping such large amounts of data is slow, and minimizing the duplicate compression processing might speed it up a bit.

Edit: I would upvote both solutions, as I think I can generate a useful heuristic from a combination of max and min file sizes and compression ratios. Unfortunately at this time, StackOverflow prevents me from upvoting anything (until I have a reputation higher than noob). Thanks for the good suggestions.

Comment: So your saying the requirement is: if a file's size when zipped up is > 2GB then don't zip it? Sounds like a strange requirement. Surely it is still worth zipping, since it will be smaller and take less time to copy/transmit?

Comment: Why not simply estimate the ratio on the fly?  Randomly sample some chunks from the file/files, try zipping those, and see what the compression ratio looks like.  As long as your samples are much smaller than Gs and you're not always right on the boundary of 2G resulting size, you'll probably get most of the achievable benefits without much work.

Comment: @MitchWheat because whoever is on the receiving end doesn't know how to handle zip64?

Comment: @MitchWheat, yes I am not sure the specifics of the receiving end, but suspect that there are legacy issues with this particular client (as per the requirements).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to estimate the zip file size is to look at the compression ratios for previously compressed files of a similar nature.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a good idea combined with @Gus to create a heuristic "best guess" estimate from file sizes could also be used to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of two ways, one simple but requires manual tuning, and the other may not provide enough benefit to justify the complexity.

1. Define a file size at which you just skip the zip attempt, and tune it to your satisfacton by hand.
2. Keep a record of the last N filesizes between the smallest failure to zip ever observed and the largest successful zip ever observed. Decide what the acceptable probability of an incorrect choice resulting in an file that should be zipped not being zipped (say 5%). set your "don't bother trying to zip" threshold such that it would have resulted in that percentage of files that would have been erroneously left unzipped.

If you absolutely can never miss an opportunity to zip file that should have been zipped then you've already got the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in this particular case the heuristic does not need to be perfect, so setting up something that skips based on file size and checking some the previous compression ratios as @Raymond Hettinger suggested with the records would probably create a very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic approach will always involve some false positives and some false negatives.

The eventual size of the zipped file will depend on a number of factors, some of which are not knowable without running the compression process itself.

Zip64 allows you to use many different compression formats, such as bzip2, LZMA, etc.
Even the compression format may do the compression differently depending on the data to be compressed. For example, bzip2 can use Burrows-Wheeler, run length encoding and Huffman among others. The eventual size of the file will then depend on the statistical properties of the data being compressed.

Take Huffman, for instance; the size of the symbol table depends on how randomly-distributed the content of the file is.

One can go on and try to profile different types of data, serialized binary, text, images etc. and each will have a different normal distribution of final zipped size.

If you really need to save time by doing the process only once, apart from building a very large database and using a rule-based expert system or one based on Bayes' Theorem, there is no real 100% approach to this problem.

You could also try sampling blocks of the file at random intervals and compressing this sample, then linearly interpolating based on the size of the file.